# varnish purge allowed only from a public ip

Tags: varnish

My setup is the following:
Nginx(443 https) -> Varnish(port 6081) -> Nginx(port 83 - the app itself)

#nginx https conf:

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
}
```

#part of default.vlc conf:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "83";
}
```

Of course, there's another nginx config for port 83, which is the application itself.
I've configured it this way, so I can run varnish behind HTTPS.

Trying to setup purge to invalidate cache for specific endpoints, I've configured the following in the default.vcl:

```
acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
    "some_public_ip"
  }

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
      if (!client.ip ~ purge) { 
         return (synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
      }
      return (purge);
    }
}
```

Everything ok, I can execute:

```
curl -X PURGE -I "https://web_server/index.php".
```

The issue is that, if I remove "127.0.0.1" from the acl list, and only let "some_public_ip", it won't work anymore. It will return "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests".
I only want the purge to work for that "some_public_ip" only.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Nginx sits in front of Varnish the `client.ip` variable always refers to it through `localhost`. The actual client IP address is stored in the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

You can extract it by calling `std.ip(req.http.X-Forwarded-For,client.ip)`. This will convert the value of `X-Forwarded-For` from a string to an IP address and will still use `client.ip` as a fallback in case of errors.

Because Nginx already sets the `X-Forwarded-For` header, Varnish will add the IP address of its client to it.

My `varnishlog` output shows the following log lines:

```
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 178.118.13.77
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 178.118.13.77, 127.0.0.1
```

We have to remove the second part in order to get the right IP address. We can do this using the following VCL snippet:

```
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For,"^([^,]+),.*$","\1");
```

In the end, this is the VCL code we need to make this work:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
    "some_public_ip"
  }

sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.X-Forwarded-For ~ ","){
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For,"^([^,]+),.*$","\1");
    }
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
      if (!std.ip(req.http.X-Forwarded-For,client.ip) ~ purge) {
         return (synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
      }
      return (purge);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried, it's the same thing. If I leave 127.0.0.1 and my public ip in the acl, it will work from any public ip, not just from mine, because if will get the request from that 127.0.0.1 like you said. If I remove the 127.0.0.1 from acl and only leave my public IP, it will send me the "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests" error.

Comment: @catalin I updated my answer: apparently Varnish adds `127.0.0.1` to the `X-Forwarded-For` header. We need to strip that part off for this example to work.

Comment: thanks friend. it works. I really appreciate.